# SAP Java SDK OData results are sometimes multiplied

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I have a small JAVA BTP app that is supposed to read master data from the SAP BP. Most of the time it works very well.

However, I have a small problem with the partner functions.
For some reason, the results is multiplied with each call. First I have correctly 6 partner functions, then 12, then 24 etc..

After 1-2 hours I have 6 correct results again.

My call in principle:

```
private void getBusinessPartnerCustomerSalesAreas() {
    Customer customer = this.businessPartner.getCustomerOrFetch();
    if (customer == null) {
        return;
    }

    this.businessPartnerCustomerSalesArea
            .addAll(customer.getCustomerSalesAreaOrFetch());

    this.getPartnerFunctions();
}

private void getPartnerFunctions() {
    this.businessPartnerCustomerSalesArea.forEach(c -> {
        this.custSalesPartnerFunctions.addAll(c.getPartnerFunctionOrFetch());
    });
}
// ...
    // partner functions output mapping
    if (!this.custSalesPartnerFunctions.isEmpty()) {
        List<CustfactsheetPartnerFunction> partnerFunctions = new ArrayList<>();
        // map partner functions to output format
        this.custSalesPartnerFunctions.forEach(p -> {
            CustfactsheetPartnerFunction partnerFunction = CustfactsheetPartnerFunction.create();
            partnerFunction.setFunction(p.getPartnerFunction());
            partnerFunction.setCustomer(p.getCustomer());
            partnerFunction.setCustomerName(p.getCustomerPartnerDescription());
            partnerFunction.setIsDefault(p.getDefaultPartner());
            partnerFunctions.add(partnerFunction);
        });
        
        returnStruc.setPartnerFunctions(partnerFunctions);
    }
```

Is there a caching somewhere which I don't see?
Other arrays (addresses for example) are not multiplied... I use the newest SDK version.
Probably I miss again only a point or so... Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any implicit caching of OData results.

Most likely your code maintains multiple copies of similar objects.

- Please check whether you populate `this.businessPartnerCustomerSalesArea` for every incoming request. It should be instantiated with every servlet call. Make sure to avoid duplicates, e.g. by leveraging `HashSet` implementation for your collection. It looks like you are filling it from *1:n* navigation properties. Without knowing the service specification, I would assume a chance for duplicates.

Or in case you use *Spring Boot*, maybe there is unexpected proxying / caching on your application.

- If you are using `@Component` in the affected code, please make sure to configure the correct scope annotation argument.
- If you are using `@Cached` or something, this would be an obvious case to check.
- If you are using dependency injection, you could try to instead load concrete implementations, hard-coded. Maybe this improves the situation, and you'll know the cause.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It helped. 
I am using Spring Boot again after many years and forgot that this is initialized as a singleton. Scope request helped...